# Maven don't build *.jar inside docker container. Why?

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, spring-boot-maven-plugin

If i delete "/target" folder in project, it run error.
Images:

```
[project directory][1]
[docker file][2]
[error][3]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti3j4.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR11Y.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j98Oj.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, `./mvnw package` is executed on your local environment, not on Docker container.

refs:

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

If you want to do on Docker container, use "`RUN cp ${JAR_FILE} <dest>`"(container to container), instead of "[`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)" (local to container).

Comment: Thank you. I did it)